# how to translate post/page content automatically at front end from one language to another language automatically

Tags: wordpress

In wordpress, intention is,
I would write post/page content in "English" language, and I would like to see this post/page in other language at front end.
So is there any plugin/way by using we can select or translate language from admin and see this post/page in selected language automatically at front/user end. (not in admin end)
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Language Translator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-language-translator/) which will use Google Translate to translate your post content to another language. Be aware that automatic translation is not entirely reliable.

Comment: sorry dreszczyk, i would not use google translator, I have review many plugin like google translator, say qtranlate, polylang etc. means I would not give any drop down from which visitor select the lang, and page translate according to that lang. I just select the lang from admin and that lang should be display at user end automatically.

Comment: @user2240424 i gave you a link: https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-language-translator/, just install this and enable widget, it will give you exactly what you want. Polylang and qtranslate is for **translating**, not **automatic translating** :)

Answer (score 0):

https://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate/
**qtranslate**
You have to select a language in backend, and it will show in front-end, but each text you have to translate in backend

Use this one, and in the backed, you can select which language you want, if you are using multisite, you are able to select language for each site.

I am using it for a while, and I am really satisfied with how it works,

Comment: I have already review this plugin, but do not want to translate from backend, and thats why I am add the words in my question that is "automatically". I want the content should be translate automatically after just selecting the language from admin.thank you.

Comment: Ok, I understand now, you can do it with google translate, you can follow those steps, I think this is what you are looking for. http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-add-google-translate-in-wordpress/